# Python/Requests - Progress bar instantly finishes?

Tags: python, download, progress-bar, tqdm

I'm trying to download an CSV file from an url, which works fine, but I can't get the progress bar to work. When I run the program, the progress bar just updates to 100% instantly, there is no constant update. I've tried so many suggestions but everytime the progress bar just instantly finishes. Would appreciate any help!

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm


def download():
    resp = s.get(url, stream=True)
    total = len(resp.content)
    with open('C:/Users/axxi/Documents/' + datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.csv', 'wb') as file, tqdm(
            total=total,
            unit='iB',
            unit_scale=True,
            unit_divisor=1024,
    ) as bar:
        for data in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            size = file.write(data)
            bar.update(size)


url = 'random url.com'
values = {'username': 'username',
          'password': 'password'}

s = requests.Session()
s.post(url, data=values, stream=True)


download()
```

Comment: What's the value of `total`? Is your response just not any bigger than 1024 bytes?

Comment: @chepner The response is 11845 bytes